# Cakephp Find Equal Operator

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to retrieve one column of ids based on a parameter being passed into my function. I want to retrieve all policy ids that have the same Coverageid that is being passed in. This is what Ive tried. I believe my Operator is in the wrong place. The reason being is when I run my script all my policies return instead of the the policies with the coverage id being passed in. I have looked around on the net but can't seem to find anything that can help me besides the PHP and Cakephp Manuals.

```
public function findPolicyIds($coverageId = null) {
    $id = $this->Policy->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => -1, array(
        'condition' => array('Policy.coverage_id == ' => '$coverageId',
        'fields' => array('Policy.id'))));

        return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function findPolicyIds($coverageId = null) {
    $id = $this->Policy->find('all', array(
        'recursive' => -1, 
        'conditions' => array('Policy.coverage_id' => $coverageId),
        'fields' => array('Policy.id')
    ));

    return $id;
}
```

Comment: This is kinda what I need but it doesn't use a comparison operator. I am trying to make sure the Policy.coverage_id is == to $coverageId. Just not sure how to implement it into my condition.

Comment: `'Policy.coverage_id' => $coverageId` applies the comparison you asked for, all Policy with `coverage_id == $coverageId`

Comment: Hmmm....ok....for some reason it is not working. It pulls all my polices. Im going to go back and check my code.

Comment: Do'h. Missed an 's' in `conditions`, probably that's why it didn't work. Please retry (updated the answer).

Comment: OMG!! You were right!! I feel like a total GOOBER!! LOL! Thanks!